# How to choose Redis add-on on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, sidekiq

I am to new to Rails and trying to use Sidekiq with Rails 4.2 on Heroku. I thus need to choose a Redis Heroku add-on, but don't really understand how to evaluate the different services (memory-size, connections..)

I'll use Sidekiq for Mailers, Push Notifications and external API calls which end up saving one object at a time.

Any advice on which add-on to choose?

Answer (score 11):

*Disclaimer - I am with Redis Labs, provider of the Redis Cloud Heroku add-on*

To get an estimate of how much memory you'll be needing and the amount of connections, do some local tests with your app. Once you have the ballpark figures, simply choose the appropriate plan from the add-on you want.

While most providers offer what appears to be the same service, Redis Cloud is the only one that actually provides an uninterrupted upgrade/downgrade procedure. That means that if you change your add-on's plan, your database remains available (with all the data, of course). AFAIK, other providers reprovision a different Redis instance when you change your plan, which requires a migration (i.e. some downtime).

Lastly, you could compare $-per-MB between the different providers - last time I checked, Redis Cloud was the cheapest and had the largest selection of plans :)

Comment: I recently switched over to Redis Lab's Memcached Cloud on Heroku because we were having problems with the Heroku Memcachier add-on.  Dealing with your support team was positive and I get the sense your team really knows what they're doing.  So you have my business.

Comment: I've been looking everywhere some study that would prove your sentence _Redis Cloud is the only one that actually provides an uninterrupted upgrade/downgrade procedure_ and anything concerning downtime. But aside the use of Sentinel, everytime I hear about Redis Lab it is called better without arguments... Could you add more explanation about HA handling somewhere? (the HA article is a bit sparse)

Comment: @UlysseBN - four years have passed since I wrote this answer, and I believe some providers have actually progressed to offer uninterrupted scaling. That said, scaling and HA are not the same thing. In any case, for information about the company's products please contact its support helpdesk at "support at redislabs dot com".